How to setup local solana validator RPC for a team about 5 PC
I want to setup a local solana validator RPC for my team, Devnet sometime gets bottleneck or something else, so I want to setup a localnet for my team. Any one can help me.

Certainly! solana-test-validator has the --bind-address, --rpc-port, --gossip-host, and --gossip-port flags, which you can specify as needed for your setup.
For example, if you set it up on a public virtual server, then you need to make sure that --gossip-host is the IP of the server, and that --rpc-port / --gossip-port are open. From there, you just need to set the address of your CLI / tools to the IP / port of your server.

thank you, I'll try it
